# Is it possible to get the binary data from an image in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera, react-native-image

I'm using `react-native-camera` and I'm having trouble getting the image as binary data in `react-native`. I need this to be able to upload images to our backend. The only thing I manage to get is uri's to the image and then maybe sending that as `FormData` to the server but that is not recommended as that would require some infrastructure change to our backend.

Is there anyone that know a solution or some tips regarding this issue?

Any thoughts or help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to get image as binary data from **react-native-camera**. I recommend to use **react-native-fs** to read uri

**Example**

```js
const RNFS = require("react-native-fs");
// response.uri from react-native-camera
RNFS.readFile(response.uri, "base64").then(data => {
  // binary data
  console.log(data);
});
```

If you want to upload image via FormData I recommend **rn-fetch-blob**

**Example**

```js
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob'
// response.uri from react-native-camera
const path = response.uri.replace("file://", "");
const formData = [];
formData.push({
  name: "photo",
  filename: `photo.jpg`,
  data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(path)
});

let response = await RNFetchBlob.fetch(
  "POST",
  "https://localhost/upload",
  {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
  },
  formData
);
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative if you're already using **react-native-camera** is upon capturing the image, you request it as *base64* directly as such:

```
takePicture = async function(camera) {
  const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true, doNotSave: true }
  const data = await camera.takePictureAsync(options)

  console.log(data.base64)
}
```

If your goal is to only snap the picture, show a preview perhaps then upload to the server and move on, then the benefit of this approach is that it won't save that photo in your device cache (`doNotSave: true`). Which means that you don't need to worry about cleaning those up after you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use '**react-native-image-crop-picker**' to pick image and video. Set following property to true

> includeBase64: true

and image file content will be available as a base64-encoded string in the data property

```
ImagePicker.openPicker({
  mediaType: "photo",
  includeBase64: true // this will give 'data' in response 
})
.then((response) => {
    console.log(resonse.data)
})
.catch((error) => {
   alert(error)
});
```