# How can I convert Base 64 data or URI data of expo-image-picker to binary file?

Tags: react-native, binary, expo, base64, expo-image-picker

I am using expo-image-picker in my React-native app. I want to convert the output of expo-image-picker to binary file but I can't. Can anyone please help me out, I am stuck in this problem for days. Thanks in advance!

I tried to use atob/btoa, but it's not working for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert base64 string image to blob in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166362/how-do-i-convert-base64-string-image-to-blob-in-react-native)

Comment: @Abe let me try first